# Swift compiler segfaults with CGRects and @objc protocols

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

While writing an iOS app I noticed a weird error with CGRects and @objc protocols.
I managed to strip my code down to this, which produces the exact same stack trace :

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol TestClassDelegate {
    optional func doSomethingWith(rect: CGRect)
}

class TestClass: NSObject {
    var delegate: TestClassDelegate?

    func callMyDelegate(myRectangle: CGRect) {
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.doSomethingWith?(myRectangle)
        }
    }
}

print("I'LL NEVER COMPILE, SO YOU'LL NEVER SEE ME")
```

Just put this code in a `main.swift` file and try to compile. I intended to raise the issue on bugs.swift.org, but perhaps there's something I don't understand going on... Any idea ?

EDIT : Here's the issue on Swift's bug tracker (you'll find a stack trace there) : https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2268

FOLLOWUP : Seems to be still broken in Swift 3 (see the issue on Swift's JIRA)

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: +1. Could reproduce the crash in playground as well. Go for bug report unless someone here explains what is happening.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 : Done, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2268